# What is the format of data packet in AODV based MANET?

Tags: network

Can anybody guide me please. I spent a lot of time over the literature to find out the data packet format of AODV routing protocol. however I found only RREQ, RREP, RERR and ACK formats, but there is no format for the data packets and its size.

Comment: Routing protocols do not route, they simply exchange routing information between routers. What gets routed are packets, such as IP. The data packets that get routed will be those of your network protocol.

Comment: @RonMaupin You should make that the answer.

Comment: @Zac67, OK, I did that. It was such a small answer that I commented.

Comment: Thank you, Sir! But let me clear pl, in a MANET/VANET we have some control messages like RREQ, RREP, RERR etc., which have some specific format/size i.e.,: source IP, source seq #, destination IP, destination seq #, hop count, etc... Now after establishing the path what will we send (data packets), Now what will be the content of that data packet format, payload size, and header content...

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Routing protocols do not route, they simply exchange routing information between routers. What gets routed are packets, such as IP. The data packets that get routed will be those of your network protocol, most likely IPv4 or IPv6.

In any case, it is unlikely that your business will use an ad hoc routing protocol because it is not completely predictable or reliable enough for most businesses. A business usually uses WAPs that report to a controller that provides centralized control and facilitates roaming.